# generate a special matrix (max value of column sum is minimum) with given number of column from a vector

Tags: r, math, optimization, statistics, combinations

Recently I come across such as a question: given a vector, one need generate a special matrix with given number of column. It should be pointed out that if the elements in the vector is not enough to fill in the generated matrix, then put 0 in the last row in the generated matrix. For the generated matrix, it has a requirement that need the maximum value of column sum is the minimum.

The following is the code for the given question:

```
x <- c(10, 10, 9, 21, 8, 3, 7, 23, 1, 5, 26)
x
ncol <- 4

x <- sort(x, decreasing = TRUE)
x

nx <- length(x)
nrow <- ceiling(nx / ncol)

# add 0 in the end
if (nx < nrow * ncol) {
  x <- c(x, rep(0, length.out = nrow * ncol - nx))
}
x
```

Here is the correct matrix, what  I want!

```
# generate mat_a
mat_a <- rbind(c(26, 23, 21, 10),
               c(5, 7, 8, 10),
               c(0, 1, 3, 9))
mat_a
# max value of column sum
max(colSums(mat_a)) # 32
```

The matrix below is what I got, but it is wrong!

```
# generate mat_b
mat_b <- rbind(c(26, 23, 21, 10),
               c(7, 8, 9, 10),
               c(0, 1, 3, 5))
mat_b
max(colSums(mat_b)) # 33
```

Since `max(colSums(mat_a)) < max(colSums(mat_b))`, `mat_a` is the wanted matrix.

From the above code, we know that `mat_a` is the wanted matrix, since `max(colSums(mat_a)) < max(colSums(mat_b))`. I understand that there are many matrices can be generated from a vector, but the matrix with the above requirement is only one (or a little if same values are generated). It seems a combinatorial algorithms or dynamic programming problem, but unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to get the solution for the above question. I appreciate it you can provide some hints about the problem or give the effective solutions.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. First you say that the code is for the given question, but later you say that cannot figure out how to get the solution (the code?) for the given question. Which is it? What exactly is the problem you are having? (Often questions for help should include the expected output and the actual output.)

Comment: @JaMiT I edited the question, where `mat_a` is the expected output, but `mat_b` is what I got, but it is wrong~

Comment: Oh, I see. You merged your output with your code. Easy to miss when one skims over the code looking for the question.

Comment: @JaMiT Thanks. It is more clear after your edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible greedy heuristic approach and probably works only where all values in `x` are non-negative.

Starting with the largest values first. Initialize the first row with the largest values. Then, add each subsequent non-zero value to the column with the smallest sum.

```
x <- c(10, 10, 9, 21, 8, 3, 7, 23, 1, 5, 26)
x <- sort(x, decreasing=TRUE)
nc <- 4L
nr <- ceiling(length(x) / 4)

#Initialize the first row with the largest values
y <- c(x[seq_len(nc)], rep(0, nc*nr-4L))
#use list to store each row of the final matrix
yl <- split(y, (seq_along(y)-1L) %% nc)

#for subsequent values
for (k in (nc+1L):length(x)) {
    #find the smallest sum among the rows provided the rows are not totally filled
    idx <- names(which.min(lapply(yl[sapply(yl, function(x) any(x==0))], sum)))

    #store this value the appropriate row
    yl[[idx]][min(which(yl[[idx]]==0L))] <- x[k]
}

#output desired matrix
matrix(unlist(yl), ncol=nc)
```

output:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   26   23   21   10
[2,]    5    7    8   10
[3,]    0    1    3    9
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. In fact, there is no negative values in the vector `x`.